# Converting JavaFX application(.Jar) to Windows application(.exe)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

can someone tell me how to convert .jar file to .exe file. I tried using Launch4j but when i try to run the .exe created by it, this error pops up. I am using jdk 11.0.4. [image]

Comment: There is jpackage which is included with the jdk in [java14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) There is also jlink which came with java 11, that would create a minimal jre so you would still have to make a batchfile of sorts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JNI error occurred after converting jar to exe launch4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075705/jni-error-occurred-after-converting-jar-to-exe-launch4j)

Comment: @matt can you please explain that procedure for java 11 ?

Comment: @Alok I'm not sure what you want me to explain, do you want to stick with launch4j, or are you trying one of the other solutions. Also, I don't have windows so I cannot help get this to work.

Comment: @smithnblack that link doesn't answer my question. That guy used jre 1.8 and included it in his application and error was resolved. But that method doesn't work for me.

Comment: @matt I just want to know what jlink does exactly and how it works.

Comment: JLink takes your modular application and bundles it with a minimal jre and dependencies. Then you can run your applicaiton with `.\\appliaction_name\\bin\\java.exe package.MainClass` The important thing to note, it isn't using the system jre, but one you bundled. You can pretty easily write a script that simplifies the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for making an installer, this video helped me a great deal [Create installer for JavaFX application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbm9_NvPnpAhXlyzgGHdaAAiAQwqsBMAJ6BAgKEAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DHkPuLj_jJd8&usg=AOvVaw1QiM1nIhkqoh9bhq3VTv2e). 
This converts your .jar into .exe installer with java jdk wrapped so you can load your .exe on any system w/o having installed java version. This uses a installer innosetup. You need to add some changes but this works like a charm.